# How to merge cells of a Word table using Office-js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I'm creating an add-in for work in which I have to reformat text to perfectly fit our designer's format.

My problem is that they used tables with an irregular number of cells. And it seems office-js isn't able to create them, even though a regular user in Word can.

[image: Weird table]

As an example, this is actually just one table with 3 rows.

The first row has 2 cells and the first is colored blue. The second has all it's borders changed to white. The second row has just one cell. The third also has just one cell with another table inside.

I know how to do all the other stuff(Change border color, embed another table, etc). What I can't figure out is how to programatically merge cells.

Office-js' [table documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/word/table.md) has no method for the purpose. Digging around I found out Excel's part of Office-js can actually do this through their [range object's merge method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#mergeacross-bool), but Word's obviously has [no such method](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/word/range.md).

**So, is there no way to merge table cells programatically with Office-js?**

Answer (score 0):

It can be done when *creating* the table using the `insertHtml` or `insertOoxml` method.

Using HTML, for example:

```
let rng = context.document.body;
let tableHTML = "<table><tr><td/><td/></tr><tr><td rowspan='2' /><td/></tr><tr><td/></tr></table>";
rng.insertHtml(tableHTML, 'End');
```

Note, however, that this will *not* execute correctly in Word On-line, which does not (yet) support merging or splitting cells. It can *display* such tables correctly, but cannot create / modify them.